# python multissh pool on windows

Tags: python, process, pool

Trying to get a process pool to work on windows but after asking me the password it again asks me the password.

```
import os
import sys 
import paramiko
import getpass
import socket
from multiprocessing import Pool


def processFunc(hostname):
 handle = paramiko.SSHClient()
 handle.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
 handle.connect(hostname, username=user, password=pw)
 print("child")
 stdin, stdout, stderr = handle.exec_command("show clock")
 cmdOutput = ""
 while True:
  try:
 cmdOutput += stdout.next()
  except StopIteration:
  break
  print("Got output from host %s:%s" % (hostname, cmdOutput))
  handle.close()

 user = "sup"
 f= open('csip.txt','r')
  hostnames = []
 for line in f:
    hostname = line.strip()
    hostnames.append(hostname)
 pw = getpass.getpass("Enter ssh password:")

 if __name__ == "__main__":
     pool = Pool(processes=4)
     pool.map(processFunc, hostnames, 1)
 pool.close()
 pool.join()
```

Am i doing something wrong? The script should read hostnames from the txt file get the password and then invoke the process pool.

Answer (score 0):

The below works -

But i want help to improve it. dont want to hardcode the username and password.

```
import os
import sys 
import paramiko
from multiprocessing import Pool

#Globals
Hostnames = []
f= open('csip.txt','r')
for line in f:
hname = line.strip()
Hostnames.append(hname)


def processFunc(Hostname):
    handle = paramiko.SSHClient()
    handle.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    handle.connect(Hostname, username="sup", password="123")
    print("child")
    stdin, stdout, stderr = handle.exec_command("show platform | i unknown")
    cmdOutput = ""
    while True:
    try:
        cmdOutput += stdout.next()
    except StopIteration:
        break
print("Got output from host %s:%s" % (Hostname, cmdOutput))
handle.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool(processes=9)
    pool.map(processFunc, Hostnames, 1)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```